# Notation question in elementary set theory - what is $\bigcup A$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Let $A$ be a set. What is defined as $\bigcup A$? Is it the union of all sets that $A$ includes? Could someone provide an example for this notation?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure $A$ is not a set of sets?

Comment: Do you mean $\bigcup A$? Usually written $$\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i$$ where $i\in I$ is simply an indexing set, and the $A_i$ together comprise a family of sets.

Comment: @dsfsf You did not respond to the comments asking whether by $UA$ you mean $\bigcup A$. But since you have accepted the answer explaining this type of notation, I went ahead and edited your post to make it clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$x\in \bigcup A\iff x\in a\text{ for some }a\in A$$

Actually: $$\bigcup A:=\left\{ x\mid\exists a\in A\; x\in a\right\} $$

Quite often you meet notations like: $$\bigcup_{i\in I}A_{i}$$ This could also be written as: $$\bigcup\left\{ A_{i}\mid i\in I\right\} $$

A set $A$ is called transitive if $x\in a\wedge a\in A$ implies
that $x\in A$. This is exactly the statement that $\bigcup A\subset A$.

Comment: Why drink from a shot glass, when you can drink from a pint? (Read: why use `\cup` when you can [and possibly should] use `\bigcup` for this notation?)

Comment: This was my first (not my last) meeting with a 'big cup':-)

Comment: I have doubts about a Dutchman telling me that he has never seeing a big cup! ;-)

Comment: haha, reasonable doubts I must say.